# Postgres 9.3 - How to change service account after install?

Tags: linux, postgresql, permissions, centos

My app uses Postgres 9.3.

I install with --serviceaccount Bill

This means that

```
  /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.3
```

script will do a

```
  su - Bill -c 'pg_ctl ....'
```

when managing services

Additionally

```
  /postgres/data/postmaster.pid
```

also belongs to this service user.

Lastly,

```
  /postgres/data
```

is owned by Bill and many of the subdirs as well.

My question is this, how can I change this service user automatically or semi automatically? Is there a --serviceaccount update command somewhere?

The last thing I want to do is search and replace every instance of Bill with the new user, and go through directories and files doing chown.

Comment: Installed via the EDB installer?

Comment: Craig, the installer I'm using is this - postgresql-9.3.2-1-linux-x64.run
Which I think means that yes it is. .